# Change text-language in android

Tags: android

my android app is nearly finished.
finally i wanna give the possibility to change the texts shown on the activitys between english and german.

is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I can imagine the situation where you want to change language of app at runtime. For example you could have an application for which you change language on the web and want to have the same setting on a phone. I had myself similar problem recently. I think this article can help you doing

https://web.archive.org/web/20210127121431/http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2009/01/force-localize-application-on-android.html

It is a matter of updating configuration.

Comment: or for a translation app where you let the user pick english to spanish, spanish to english, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it better to let user decide their locale and language settings through android itself ?

Regards, 
 Stéphane

Comment: so... if the phone is set on another language, all apps are displayed in this language automatically? wow, didn't know that, thanks

Comment: There can be such situation: phone doesn't have needed locale, but app does, in this case app will not be able auto switch to needed locale.